# How are Swing components internally created, laid out, repainted, notified of events, ...?

Tags: java, user-interface, swing, graphics, awt

I wonder if there's a good documentation (or a (viewable) ebook) about
the **lifecycle of Swing components**.

*Is "lifecycle" the correct term, anyway?*

I hope to find answers to question such as:

- How, when, in which order **painting methods** are called?
- How, when, which **events** are called by whom?
- What is the exact **sequence** of method calls for component creation?

From time to time I encounter strange behavior of my apps, for example:

- ComponentListener's **resize event** is called before **setVisible(true)**
  (so that root pane has negative dimensions!)
- Some components are laid out correctly only after resizing the JFrame **by hand**
- Changing a super class from JPanel to JLayeredPane causes my class
  to be laid out differently inside an other container.
- And lot of other strange things...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same question long ago.

I can't believe how hard is to find a good resource about this topic in the internet.

Fortunately I've found this link and now I have it in my bookmark with golden tag. :)

[A Swing Architecture Overview](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/architecture-142923.html)

Once you have a good grasp of how they work conceptually you will be able to fix most of the problems you mention.

I hope it helps.